# Date picker invalid time value error in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby

Here my code:

1. Set date

```
    this.state = {
        startDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    }
```

2. Set this startDate into datepicker(react-datepicker):

```
    DatePicker
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleDateChange.bind(this)}
```

3. And gives error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, after checking react-datepicker documentation I found some helpful information regarding this issue. That is "**Up until version 1.8.0, this package was using Moment.js. Starting v2.0.0, we switched to using date-fns, which uses native Date objects, to reduce the size of the package.**" `react-datepicker` before version 2, it use `moment` for date type, after version 2, it use `js date` type Please check this [documentation link](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) .

To fix this issue we have 2 ways,

1. I you're using `react-datepicker` 2.5.0 + typescript +
   "@types/react-datepicker": "^1.1.7" + momentjs. Upgrade
   "@types/react-datepicker": "^2.3.0". typescript shall give you that
   error.

(OR)

2. Just change the date to `this.state = { startDate:
   moment().toDate().format('YYYY-MM-DD') }`  because the selected
   `prop` of the `DatePicker` react component requires a **Date
   object**.